# PHP - fill array same value

Tags: php, arrays, fill

[Solved]

I want create array consist 40 elements (10x values "c", 10x values "d", 10x values "h", 10x values "s").
I try create array:

```
$znaczki = array_fill(0, $iloscZnaczkow, 'c');
$znaczki = array_fill($iloscZnaczkow, $iloscZnaczkow, 'd');
$znaczki = array_fill((2 * $iloscZnaczkow), $iloscZnaczkow, 'h');
$znaczki = array_fill((3 * $iloscZnaczkow), $iloscZnaczkow, 's');
```

Var $IloscZnaczkow contains number - 10.
Unfortunetlly, later I will use $znaczki and script

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($serializ as $key => $value) {
    echo '<img src="images/' . $value . $znaczki[$i] . '.gif" />';
    $i++;
}
```

throw image src="images/11.gif" (it doesn't have $znaczki[$i] everywhere :()

Comment: where is $serializ coming from ?

Comment: What does `$serializ` contains?

Comment: Also, pls make var_dump of `$znaczki` after array filling.

Comment: I mean where has OP defined this variable ? AS far as I'm concerned this variable could be an array as much as it could be a cheese pizza... Can OP please `var_dump()` all variables ?

Comment: mmmmm, cheese pizza with array filling.

Comment: What is in `$serializ`?

Comment: $serializ is download from MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you keep overwriting the array:

```
$znaczki = array_merge(
    array_fill(0, $iloscZnaczkow, 'c'),
    array_fill(0, $iloscZnaczkow, 'd'),
    array_fill(0, $iloscZnaczkow, 'h'),
    array_fill(0, $iloscZnaczkow, 's')
);
```

is what you want. You don't really need the index math anymore, as array_merge will maintain the indices for you.